# php + mysql to insert many rows with incremental ids and different values

Tags: php, mysql, stress-testing

I'm trying to stress my application to see if the mysql queries are OK for a large set of records.

As many developers, I wrote the PHP/MySQL application having a small range of records and adding couple of them on the development stage.
Now, I'm wondering how is gonna work (slow, normal or fast) if I will have 10000 or 50000 rows in my tables. Of course all data is in many tables (clients, contact, orders, products, carts etc)

To achieve this I will need to duplicate rows with incremental ids and different values.

Now, I know it's impossible to ask to write queries for all my tables or database structure so, my question is:

How can I insert into a mysql table multiple rows with incremental ids and different values? Can be an SQL style or a PHP code as soos as it can be executed.

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `ID_Customer` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Name` varchar(50) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `Address` varchar(100) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `Zip` varchar(15) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `ID_Country_Subdivision_ISO_Code` char(3) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `ID_Country_ISO_Code` char(2) character set latin1 default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID_Customer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci;


INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES ('9', 'Bernard Dusablon', '8-125 103 E Avenue', 'St-Jérôme', 'J7Y 3Z6', 'QC', 'CA');
INSERT INTO `customers` VALUES ('10', 'Nicolas Gilbert', '9-125 103 E Avenue', 'Montréal', 'H7C 1T5', 'QC', 'CA');
```

Comment: I don't understand. You asking how to insert and auto increment value be different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Have a look into [Generate Data](http://www.generatedata.com/#about)**, from there generate at least 500k results of rows and insert them into your database.

I recomend at least 500k because less than that you wont even be able to feel not-indexed queries and stuff like that. If you just test it against 10k, all queries will be lightning fast (indexed or not).

You should then stress-test your site using both:

[Apache ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) - that will put load into your server (and db)
[MysqlSlap](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/howdoi/how-do-i-stress-test-mysql-with-mysqlslap/133) - that will put load on the database

If you then happen to have trouble on any single query take a look at the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) command that MySQL has. It will pinpoint where your problem is.

Comment: I like this approach. I will try to do it this way, at least for the generatedata.com

Answer (score 1):

As OldCode101 hinted, you don't need to include your "ID_Customer" field when you insert.  If you exclude it, then auto_increment takes effect, and the MySQL server is responsible for assigning a new, unique value.  If you need to use that value, you can use the [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id) function from PHP.

That answers the "How do I use auto_increment" question.

To stress-test your database with many rows, you should figure out a query that you think might be done frequently, then time that query with different numbers of rows in the database.

```
$q_insert = "INSERT INTO customers (Name, Zip) VALUES ('%s', '%s')";
$q_test = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE ZIP LIKE '%s')";

$i = 0;
while ($i++ < 10) {
  $n = 0;
  for ($n=0; $n<10000; $n++) {
    $randomname = substr(md5(time()),0,rand(5,10)) ." ". substr(md5(time()),10,rand(5,10));
    mysql_query(sprintf($q_insert, $randomname, rand(10000,99999)));
  }
  $starttime=microtime(1);
  mysql_query(sprintf($q_test, rand(1,9)));
  printf("i=%s, duration=%.4f s\n", $i, microtime(1)-$starttime);
}
```

Untested.  YMMV.

Comment: thanks. This should work but I prefer the lazy solution of Frankie. Generatedata.com  Regarding the stress of app, I thought to the same thing. I have one page that have an heavy sql transaction on it (multiple queries on multiple tables). thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a randomizer PHP script to fire off an insert statement. DO NOT INCLUDE THE ID_CUSTOMER field in your insert, the SQL Server will take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like in PHP

```
$max_stress_test = 100;
for(i=0;i<=$max_stress_test;i++)
{
  $query = 'INSERT INTO `customers` (Name, Address, Zip, ID_Country_Subdivision_ISO_Code, ID_Country_ISO_Code) VALUES ('Bernard Dusablon', '8-125 103 E Avenue', 'St-Jérôme', 'J7Y 3Z6', 'QC', 'CA');'

  $result = mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error() );
}
```

It will loop and add rows to your table until it reaches 100. The `ID_Customer` will go up automatically.

I am sure there are stress test tools out there to use though.

Comment: I agree but, I need to randomize the data too.

Answer (score 0):

You also can create simple function in SQL as follows

[This is link to create the function](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions)

make a for loop, with random values.

[This link will explain the use of SQL RAND()](http://www.coderecipes.net/sql-random-function.aspx)

I think this will surely help..!